# R- pareto chart grouping like histogram

Tags: r, graph, pareto-chart

I need to create a Pareto chart in R. From the example of "qcc" library I need to do grouping before:

let's suppose my table is:

```
defect <- data.frame(a=c(8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1))
```

If a do a histogram I get the grouping automatically

```
hist(defect$a, breaks=c(-1:8))
```

[image]

But with a pareto graph I don't:

```
pareto.chart(defect$a, ylab = "Error frequency")
```

[image]

**Is there a way to get the grouping and the chart without having to group it with ddply?**
I need to get the same result of the following, but without having to group it manually.

```
bb<-ddply(defect$a, .(a), count)
pareto.chart(bb$a, ylab = "Error frequency")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation it seems pretty clear that the `pareto.chart` function expects summarized data. If you don't want to use `ddply()` you could use the base `table()` function

```
pareto.chart(table(defect$a), ylab = "Error frequency")
```