# Fit the cumulative percentage line to the sorted histogram output with d3 for a pareto chart histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, pareto-chart, cumulative-line-chart

This is what I have so far: https://gist.github.com/daluu/fc1cbcab68852ed3c5fa and http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/fc1cbcab68852ed3c5fa. I'm trying to replicate Excel functionality.

The line fits the default histogram just fine as in the base/original http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/f58884c24ff893186416. And I'm able to sort the histogram in descending frequency, although in doing so, I switched x scales (from linear to ordinal). I can't seem to map the line to the sorted histogram correctly at this point. It should look like the following examples in terms of visual representation:

- the Excel screenshot in a [comment in my gist](https://gist.github.com/daluu/fc1cbcab68852ed3c5fa#gistcomment-1685405) referenced above
- the pareto chart sorted histogram in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554817/r-pareto-chart-grouping-like-histogram?rq=1)
- the pareto chart (similar to but not exactly a sorted histogram) made with d3 [here](http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/d43ec5e610dd5dedbbe1)

What's the best design approach to get the remaining part working? Should I have started with a single x scale and not need to switch from linear to ordinal? If so, I'm not sure how to apply the histogram layout correctly using an ordinal scale or how not to use a linear x scale as a source of input to the histogram layout and still get the desired output.

Using the same ordinal scale with the code I have so far, the line looks ok but it's not the curve I am expecting to see.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did my solution answer your question?

Comment: yes, that does, close enough for me to work with. sorry, forgot to follow up on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the line is that the cumulative distribution needs to be recalculated after the bar is sorted, or if you're gunning for a static pareto chart, the cumulative distribution needs to be calculated in the target sort order. For this purpose i've created a small function to do this calculation:

```
function calcCDF(data){
  data.forEach(function(d,i){
      if(i === 0){
      d.cum = d.y/dataset.length
    }else{
      d.cum = (d.y/dataset.length) + data[i-1].cum
    }
  })
  return data
}
```

In my case, i'm toggling the pareto sort on/off and recalculating the d.cum property each time. One could theoretically create two cumulative dist properties to start with; i.e. d.cum for a regular ordered distribution and say d.ParetoCum for the sorted cumulative, but i'm using d.cum on a tooltip and decided against that.

Per the axis, i'm using a single ordinal scale which i think is cleaner, but required some work on getting the labels to be meaningful for number ranges since tick-marks and labels no longer delineate the bins as one would get with a linear scale. My solution here was to just use the number range as the tick mark e.g. "1 - 1.99" and add a function to alternate tickmarks (got that solution a while ago from [Alternating tick padding in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407347/alternating-tick-padding-in-d3-js)).

For the bar sorting, i'm using this d3 example as a reference in case you need to understand in the context of a simpler/smaller example.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3fhrcxp/3/) that incorporates all of the above. If you want to use it, i would suggest adding a check to avoid the user being able to toggle off both bars and line (left a note in the code...should be trivial)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting the y.

```
data.sort(function(a,b){ return b.y - a.y;});
```

you should be sorting the x

```
data.sort(function(a,b){ return a.x - b.x;});
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/A34r30OUuN9stc1mhGsl?p=preview)

Comment: Sorting by x isn't the intended behavior. If you look at the gist link, the comment with Excel screenshot, that's how the chart should look (e.g. a pareto chart histogram). Sorted by highest bin count, descending order. Bin count frequency is y not x. Didn't check, maybe the line could be right, but the bin presentation isn't with your solution. I just looked at the rendered chart preview.

Comment: Not sure if i understaood your problem well but i think you should be using the guide x on sortedXScale like  `var guide = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function(d){ return sortedXScale(d.x) +sortedXScale.rangeBand()/2 })
              .y(function(d){ return ycum(d.cum) })
              .interpolate('linear');
` plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/hOh2tzKBFyXE49m19BMe?p=preview

Comment: That's closer to what I'm looking  for, but it should really look like the [colored bar charts with a line here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554817/r-pareto-chart-grouping-like-histogram?rq=1), or [this d3 sample](http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/d43ec5e610dd5dedbbe1) of mine, which is the same type of chart but not histogram (layout) built (i.e. is a custom chart). In your sample, the line isn't messed up like my OP, but it's not the right curve either.